# Change Div Class On Each Click

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am building Bootstrap HTML and PHP website. Basically I need a solution so that when a div is clicked on it changes color and adds some text.

I can do this however I need a solution so that it can be done 3 times, bronze, silver and gold in this instance.

Below is my JSFiddle which shows it working, it changes to bronze and inserts the text as it should however the second click will not work and the third click won't work.

https://jsfiddle.net/vvecu9qa/1/

Hope that makes sense,

Thanks in advance guys!

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Spin on a variety of body parts</td>
        <td>Spin with control and body tension</td>
        <td>Spin in a variety of shapes</td>
        <td>Identify appropriate places to perform a spin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">Jon Smith</a></td>
        <td class="progress1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="progress2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="progress3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="progress4">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**CSS**

```
.emerging {
  background-color: #cd7f32;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.expected {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.exceeding {
  background-color: #ffd700;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.progress1').click(function(){
  $(".progress1").removeClass("progress1");
  $(this).addClass('emerging');
  $(this).text('Emerging');
});
$('.emerging').click(function(){
  $(".emerging").removeClass("emerging");
  $(this).addClass('expected');
  $(this).text('Expected');
});
$('.expected').click(function(){
  $(".expected").removeClass("expected");
  $(this).addClass('exceeding');
  $(this).text('Exceeding');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your script like this, it will work

```
$(document).on("click",'.progress1',function(){
    $(".progress1").removeClass("progress1");
    $(this).addClass('emerging');
     $(this).text('Emerging');
});

$(document).on("click",'.emerging',function(){
    $(".emerging").removeClass("emerging");
    $(this).addClass('expected');
    $(this).text('Expected');
});

$(document).on("click",'.expected',function(){
    $(".expected").removeClass("expected");
    $(this).addClass('exceeding');
    $(this).text('Exceeding');
});
```

here is the updated [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/vvecu9qa/3/)

Comment: I tried to first time round but it said I had to wait 5 minutes, sorted that for you. Thanks again mate.

Comment: glad that it helped you:)

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have 3 scenarios, your approach is fine. However, a more intuitive approach would be to create an array and an index, then cycle through them. This way you would only need one click event instead of 1 per step.

[Updated Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/vvecu9qa/4/)

```
var classes = ['emerging', 'expected', 'exceeding'];
var index = 0;

$('.progress1').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass(); //Removes all classes

    $(this).addClass(classes[index]);
    $(this).text(classes[index]);

    if(index == (classes.length - 1)) {
        index = 0; //Reset index at end of array
    } else {
        index++; //Increment index if not at the end of array
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. I have used the data attribute to make it a bit cleaner.

https://jsfiddle.net/mvinayakam/m4q3rgrq/

```
        <td class="progress" data-progress="base" ><span>&nbsp;<span></td>
```

The Javascript part

```
$('.progress').click(function(){
progressAttr=this.getAttribute('data-progress');
switch (progressAttr)
{
    case "base":
            this.setAttribute('data-progress',"emerging");
            break;
    case "emerging":
            this.setAttribute('data-progress',"exceeding");
            break;
}
```

});

The CSS

[data-progress="emerging"] {
   /* Styles */
    background-color: #cd7f32;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

[data-progress="emerging"]:after {
    content:"Emerging";
}